# Error:The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I need to get multile items from dynamodb using lambda with node.js. I am using batchGet method of AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(). I get below error.

```
{
    "errorMessage": "The provided key element does not match the schema",
    "errorType": "ValidationException",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)",
        "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)",
        "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)",
        "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
        "Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
        "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)"
    ]
}
```

Below is my code .

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const params = {
  RequestItems: {
    "usersTable_Test": {
      Keys: [{
        userId: '123'}
      ],
      ProjectionExpression: "userId"
    }
  }
};
const res = await docClient.batchGet(params).promise();
```

I have also tried batchGetItem method but then I get below error.

```
{
    "errorMessage": "docClient.batchGetItem is not a function",
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:62:30)",
        "<anonymous>",
        "process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What are the keys on your table?

Comment: If `userId` is not your primary key then this query will not work. Also, `batchGetItem` will only work if you remove the `.DocumentClient()` from AWS.DynamoDB(), and the parameter syntax for that request is very different.

Comment: Another thing to check, is userId stored as a number, or a string? You are passing 123 as a string, remove the quotes if the db is storing the value as a number.

Comment: @Dylan I have userId as primary partition key and refId as primary sort key. Data type for both is String.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using a sort key, you will have to include that in your parameters as well. If you were to create the database without setting up a sort key, you would only need the primary key. The ProjectExpression is also not needed in this case.
Documentation for batchGet(): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchGet-property

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const params = {
  RequestItems: {
    "usersTable_Test": {
      Keys: [
        {
          userId: '123',
          refId: 'theRefId'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
const res = await docClient.batchGet(params).promise();
```

If you want to get data by only the primary key, you can use the `query()` method.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var params = {
  TableName: 'usersTable_Test',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'userId = :i',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':i': '123'
  }
};

docClient.query(params).promise();
```